# Simplify $\int F(x+a)dF(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Any hints on how to simplify

$$\int_a^b F(x+c)dF(x),$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$, $F(x)$ is a CDF of random variable $X$ and its PDF $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable over the support $[-\infty, \infty].$

I played around with integration by parts, but did not achieve too much.

Comment: This is the so-called convolution of $F$ with itself evaluated at $-c$. There is no general formula for this.